# EF Core - code first - multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core, cascading-deletes

*I know a lot has been written about that subject, so let me say first I carefully read first 2 pages on [Google about this topic](https://www.google.si/search?q=entity%20framework%20core%20multiple%20cascade%20paths%20site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1ASUM_enSI731SI735&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHmuzO-7vZAhUpBcAKHWTjCT8QrQIIMSgEMAA&biw=1920&bih=1069).*

Many suggest to put `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`, and `dotnet ef database update` does not complain anymore. Problem solved until you try to delete record.

I have exactly the same problem as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45128535/3170087), which is duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36371216/3170087). Proposed solution in second link is:

> You are expected to break the cycle. You can do that by turning off
>   cascade delete (by including WillCascadeOnDelete(false) in the
>   respective relationship configuration) for at least one of the
>   relationships customers->payments or  customers->billingCenters.

This is what I research so far.
Now let's get to the problem (again). I have diamond relationship:
[image: Schema]

All ForeignKeys must be `not null`. So setting one foreign key to allow null is not an option. I would also like that user can delete:

- Parameter-Value-Parts -> No problem here
- Parameter-Values      -> No problem here
  `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`
- Parameter-Parts       -> No problem here
  `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`
- Parameters            -> Big problem

To follow [answer on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36371650/3170087), I could break cycle between `Parameter-Parts` and `Parameter-Value-Parts` with `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)`.
This would allow me to delete `Parameter`, but now I can not delete `Parameter-Parts`.

I could manually delete all `Parameter-Value-Parts` before deleting `Parameter-Parts`, but I would like to avoid manually deletion. Is that possible?

I also read on SO, that all `cascade delete` should be avoided in application and developer should manually take care of deleting dependent table rows before row deletion. What is consider best practice?
Delete cascade seems easy solution, but I am not searching for an easy solution but the right one. The one that would scale easily on large data model in large application.

Comment: A real diamond relation wouldn't work on simple ID keys but they would come with some shared key part as far as I remember...

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand your requirements correctly.

If you want a real diamond shape, then it would be required for `ParameterValueParts` to reference `ParameterValues` and `ParameterParts` that in turn reference the same `Parameter`. This would be modelled by composite keys in SQL:

```cs
class Parameter
{
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }
}

class ParameterValue
{
    // composite key of ParameterId, ValueId with ParameterId also being a foreign key
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }
    public int ValueId { get; set; }
}

class ParameterPart
{
    // composite key of ParameterId, PartId with ParameterId also being a foreign key
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }
}

class ParameterValueParts
{
    // key
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // three foreign keys:
    // ParameterId as foreign key to Parameter
    // ParameterId, ValueId are the composite foreign key to ParameterValue
    // ParameterId, PartId are the composite foreign key to ParameterPart
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }
    public int ValueId { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }
}
```

This way, you can have many combinations of `ParameterValue` and `ParameterPart` but each combination is required to belong to a specific `Parameter`. With this basic design, I never had any cascade issues in my projects.

Side note: you can configure the `ValueId` and `PartId` as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` in their respective classes in order to not handle ID values manually. (at least in EF6, I hope EF Core works similar in this regard)